# SemanticException [Error 10007]: Ambiguous column reference _c1

Tags: hadoop, hive, jira, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm facing issue while using four level of nesting in a hive query. Below is the query which I'm executing -

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(qtod.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY qtod.id, qtod.year_begin_date ORDER BY qtod.tran_date)
FROM (SELECT *, 
    SUM(mtod.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY mtod.id, mtod.quarter_begin_date ORDER BY mtod.tran_date)
    FROM (SELECT *, 
        SUM(wtod.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY wtod.id, wtod.month_begin_date ORDER BY wtod.tran_date)
        FROM (select id,
            year_begin_date,
            quarter_begin_date,
            month_begin_date,
            week_begin_date,
            tran_date,
            amount,
            SUM(amount) 
OVER (PARTITION BY id,week_begin_date ORDER BY tran_date) FROM table_name)wtod)mtod)qtod;
```

If I'm excluding fourth level nesting it is working fine, but while including it, getting below Error msg -

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10007]: Ambiguous column reference
>   _c1 in qtod

To avoid nesting i have tried to do it in other way

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT id,year_begin_date,tran_date,amount,SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY id,year_begin_date ORDER BY tran_date) FROM yeartodate)ytod
    JOIN 
(SELECT *, SUM(mtod.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY mtod.id, mtod.quarter_begin_date ORDER BY mtod.tran_date)
FROM (SELECT *, SUM(wtod.amount) OVER (PARTITION BY wtod.id, wtod.month_begin_date ORDER BY wtod.tran_date)
FROM (select id,
    year_begin_date,
    quarter_begin_date,
    month_begin_date,
    week_begin_date,
    tran_date,
    amount,
    SUM(amount) 
OVER (PARTITION BY id,week_begin_date ORDER BY tran_date) FROM table_name)wtod)mtod)qtod
ON qtod.id=ytod.id AND qtod.tran_date=ytod.tran_date;
```

Still getting same Error.
after searching on web i found it's an issue with hive itself according to [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7733) raised for hive

As **jira is fixed** now and patch is **available in hive 14**, so i tried to run it on hive 14(HDP). 
Still getting the same **Error**.
Please write your suggestion.....

Answer (score 2):

Non-aliased function calls within a `SELECT` are mapped to column names `_c1`, `_c2`, etc. In this case you have a single non-aliased function call per `SELECT`, so they all create a column `_c1`.

The issue is that because you are doing a `SELECT *` from the next sub-query down and then appending another function call that maps to `_c1` then you have the same column named twice, and hence an error around an ambiguous column reference.

The solution should be to alias all of your function calls so that they do not use the `_c1` default name, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT id,year_begin_date,tran_date,amount,SUM(amount) AS ytod_amount_sum OVER (PARTITION BY id,year_begin_date ORDER BY tran_date) FROM yeartodate)ytod
    JOIN 
(SELECT *, SUM(mtod.amount) AS mtod_amount_sum OVER (PARTITION BY mtod.id, mtod.quarter_begin_date ORDER BY mtod.tran_date)
FROM (SELECT *, SUM(wtod.amount) AS wtod_amount_sum OVER (PARTITION BY wtod.id, wtod.month_begin_date ORDER BY wtod.tran_date)
FROM (select id,
    year_begin_date,
    quarter_begin_date,
    month_begin_date,
    week_begin_date,
    tran_date,
    amount,
    SUM(amount) AS amount_sum
OVER (PARTITION BY id,week_begin_date ORDER BY tran_date) FROM table_name)wtod)mtod)qtod
ON qtod.id=ytod.id AND qtod.tran_date=ytod.tran_date;
```